# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading

Tags: javascript, html

Hola buenas en esta parte de mi codigo me dice:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')**

Siendo que el `id` lo capturo desde el botón, cabe destacar que ambos carrito y arreglo son *arrays*, con el método *find* es para preguntar si `id==id` que llega  existe o no , pero me dice que está indefinido
`itemCarrito` e `itemProducto` me sale *undefined*.

Pareciera que no está recorriendo el arreglo.

```
let itemProducto = arreglo.find(a=> a.id==id);
  console.log(itemProducto)
  
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  console.log(itemCarrito)
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')**

```js
const Clickbutton = document.querySelectorAll('#articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')

let carrito = []
let arreglo = []

Clickbutton.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', addToCarritoItem)
})
  
//const itemImg = item.querySelector('.card-img-top').src;
  
//función para convertir un template con variables --> https://medium.com/@mrg101/this-is-great-thinking-2153c8982152
function interpolate(template, params) {
  template = template.toString().trim()
  const replaceTags = { '&': '&amp;', '<': '&lt;', '>': '&gt;', '(': '%28', ')': '%29' };
  const safeInnerHTML = text => text.toString().replace(/[&<>\(\)]/g, tag => replaceTags[tag] || tag);
  const keys = Object.keys(params);
  const keyVals = Object.values(params).map(safeInnerHTML);
  return new Function(...keys, `return \`${template}\``)(...keyVals);
 }

function addToCarritoItem(e,id){
    const button=e.target
    const item = button.closest('.tr');
     //const td=document.getElementById('button').parentNode;
    // const tr=document.querySelector('td_'+id).parentNode;
    //console.log(tr)
    
    const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;
  const codigo = item.querySelector('.codigo').textContent;
  const nombre = item.querySelector('.nombre').textContent;
  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;
  const talla_ropa = item.querySelector('.talla_ropa').textContent;
  //const itemImg = item.querySelector('.card-img-top').src;

  const Productos = {
    id: id_prod,
    codigo: codigo,
    nombre: nombre,
    cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponible,
    talla: talla,
    talla_ropa: talla_ropa,
    //img: itemImg,
    cantidad:1,
    precio:0    
    
  }

  let itemProductos = Productos;
  arreglo.push(itemProductos)

  console.log(arreglo)

  let itemProducto = arreglo.find(a=> a.id==id);
  console.log(itemProducto)
  
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  console.log(itemCarrito)
    if(itemCarrito){
       //console.log("Producto ya existe en carrito");
      if (itemProducto.cantidad_disponible<=itemCarrito.cantidad){
        return;
      }
      console.log("Repetido");
     itemCarrito.cantidad++;
      document.getElementById("PRE_" +id).value=itemCarrito.cantidad;
    }
    else{
      console.log("NO Repetido");
      itemCarrito = structuredClone(itemProducto); //creamos un clon para agregarlo al carrito
     
      carrito.push(itemCarrito);
      
      //renderiza (agrega) un producto a la tabla de carrito
      carrito_content.innerHTML+= interpolate(templateRowCarrito.innerHTML,itemCarrito);
    }
    
   //updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);
  }
//updatecantidad(id,itemCarrito.cantidad);

   renderCarrito() 

function renderProductos(){
//renderiza todos los productos
for (let index = 0; index < document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .id_n').length; index++) {
  var id_ncap= document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .id_n')[index].textContent
  var idcap= document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .id_prod')[index].textContent

  var codigocap= document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .codigo')[index].textContent
  
  var nombrecap= document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .nombre')[index].textContent
  
   var cantidad_disponiblecap= document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .cantidad_disponible')[index].textContent
  var tallacap=  document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .talla');[index].textContent
  var talla_ropacap= document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content > .tr > .talla_ropa')[index].textContent
   
    let Productos = {
      id_n: id_ncap,
      id: idcap,
      codigo: codigocap,
      nombre: nombrecap,
      cantidad_disponible: cantidad_disponiblecap,
      talla: tallacap,
      talla_ropa: talla_ropacap
  
      //img: itemImg,
    };
    
    var productos_content= document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > #productos_content')
productos_content.innerHTML="";

  productos_content.innerHTML=Productos
  }
}

function updatecantidad(id,valor){
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);

  //document.getElementById("Q_"+id).innerText=GetMax(id)-valor;
  itemCarrito.cantidad=valor;
  updateTotal(itemCarrito);
}
function updateprecio(id,valor){
  let itemCarrito = carrito.find(a=> a.id==id);
  itemCarrito.precio=valor;
  updateTotal(itemCarrito);
}
function updateTotal(item){
 document.getElementById("T_"+item.id).innerText= item.cantidad * item.precio;
}

 function renderCarrito(){
  const button = document.createElement('input')
  
  button.type = 'button';
  button.id = 'submit';
  button.value = 'Guardar';
  button.className = 'guardar';    
   
  var Content=""
carrito.map(item => {
  
    const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
    tr.setAttribute("id", `C_${item.id}`)
//     <td class="table__productos">
         
//     <input type="text" id="id_productos" disabled style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;
// " name="id_productos" class="id_productos" value="${item.id}"></>
//       <h6 class="title" hidden>${item.id}</h6>
      
//       </td>
    Content = `
    <th scope="row">${item.id}</th>

    <td class="table__productos">
    <input id="id_productos" type="text" value="${item.id}" class="id_productos"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">

      <h6 class="title" hidden>${item.id}</h6>
    </td>

    <td class="table__codigo">
    <input id="codigo" type="text" value="${item.codigo}" class="codigo"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__nombre">
    <input id="nombre" type="text" value="${item.nombre}" class="nombre"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
     
    </td>
    
    <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
    <input id="cantidad_disponible" type="text" value="${item.cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla">
    <input id="talla" type="text" value="${item.talla}" class="talla"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla_ropa">
    <input id="talla_ropa" type="text" value="${item.talla_ropa}" class="talla_ropa"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
    </td>
    
    <td class="table__cantidad">
      <input type="number" min="0" id="PRE_${item.id}" value="${item.cantidad}" class="input__elemento">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__precio">
    <input id="precio" type="text" class="precio">
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__delete">
    <button class="delete btn btn-danger">x</button>
      
    </td>

    `
    tr.innerHTML = Content 
    tbody.append(tr)
    
   // tr.querySelector(".delete").addEventListener('click', removeItemCarrito)
   
  }  
    
  )
    
}
```

```html
<template id="templateRowCarrito">
 <tr id="C_${id}">
  <td>${nombre}</td>
  
  <td><input type="number" value="${cantidad}" id="PRE_${id}"  min="0"></td>
  <td><input type="number" value="${precio}"  min="0"></td>
  <td id="T_${id}"></td>
 </tr>
</template> 

<table id="tabla" class="table">
           
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
                <TH>id del producto</TH>
                <TH>Codigo</TH>
                <TH>producto</TH>
                <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
              
                <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>talla ropa</TH>
                <TH>Añadir </TH>
                <TH>Añadir </TH>  
                <TH>Añadir </TH>
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <table id="tabla" class="table">
           
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
                <TH>id del producto</TH>
                <TH>Codigo</TH>
                <TH>producto</TH>
                <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
              
                <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>talla ropa</TH>
                <TH>Añadir </TH>
                <TH>Añadir </TH>  
                <TH>Añadir </TH>
            </tr>
               <tbody id="productos_content" class="tbody">
               <td class="id_n">15</td>
                <td class="id_prod">15</td>
                <td class="codigo">EAN_001</td>
                <td class="nombre"> PERICO</td>
                <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 5</td>
                <td class="talla">38</td>
                <td class="talla_ropa">S</td>
                <td class="td"><button  class="button" onclick="(e)=> addToCarritoItem(e,15)">Añadir</button></td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Tal y como está escrita no queda muy clara la pregunta. ¿Puedes darle a [edit] y reescribir un poco lo que quieres obtener? Veo en el código un `id` que no se le está pasando a la función, pero no sé de dónde quieres obtenerlo. Usa código (texto) en lugar de imágenes, será más fácil verlo y manipularlo

Comment: ¿De verdad es necesario tanto código para mostrar tu problema? Creo que te vendría bien preparar un [mcve], pues eso aumentaría tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.